# Restart a process if cpu usage is more than 90% for more than a 60sec

Tags: systemd, limit, ulimit, cpu-usage

Normally one of my `systemd` services will take about 0...5% cpu Usage. In some cases it can reach up to 100% but only for some seconds. If the Service "crashes" it takes up to 100% continuously.

**So I want to supervise the service and restart the service, when it has more than 90% cpu usage over a time of 60sec. How can I do this?**

I'm looking for something similar to `prlimit --cpu`. But as I understand it will limit the total cpu time.